# Navigator inside PopupMenuItem does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to call `Navigator` inside the `onTap` property of a `PopupMenuItem` it doesn't work:

```
PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
  return [
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text('Edit'),
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditorPage())),
    ),
  ];
}),
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The popup menu is popping its own route before calling the callback, a way to fix this is to use the `onSelected` property of the `PopupMenuButton` itself:

```
//---add onSelected to your PopupMenuButton
PopupMenuButton(onSelected: (result) {
  if (result == 0) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditorPage()));
  }
}, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
  return [
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: 0, //---add this line
      child: Text('Edit'),
    ),
  ];
}),
```

Answer (score 25):

When a pop up menu is clicked, it will call `pop()` on the navigator to dismiss itself. So pushing an extra route would cause it to pop that route immediately, instead of dismissing itself.

Knowing this, we can change the order of the two events by slightly delaying the `push()` operation by `0 ms`. This causes the callback to be pushed on to the event queue and thus will be executed after the menu is popped.

```
  PopupMenuItem(
    child: Text('Open Settings'),
    onTap: () async {
      final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
      await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
      navigator.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SettingsPage()),
      );
    },
  )
```

We can further shorten the above code to:

```
onTap: () => Future(
  () => Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SettingsPage()),
  ),
)
```

Comment: That is really weird behaviour. I would never of figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: Was stuck into this for a while. missed `event.preventDefault()` a lot. BTW, nice solution! Thanks!